# elements hide with jquery issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am hiding elements on click event. I have input checkbox elements and on click i hide these elements. It is working fine in firefox but in chrome, elements hide but there is some space left. I have attached the images. please tell me if someone has any hint,

[image: without hidden][image: with hidden elements in chrome]!

[image]

code is kind of this,

```
<div id="cat">  
            <div id="cat-head">
                <img src="opeb-arrow.png"></img>
                <h2 id="filter-heading"><b>Frame Styles</b></h2>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox"><span>Geek&nbsp;(123)</span></input><br>
            <input type="checkbox"><span>Round&nbsp;Eye&nbsp;(3435)</span></input><br>
            <input type="checkbox"><span>Cat&nbsp;Eye&nbsp;(5675)</span></input><br>
            <input type="checkbox"><span>Wayfarer&nbsp;(234)</span></input><br>
            <input type="checkbox"><span>Aviator&nbsp;(545)</span></input><br>
        </div>
```

javascript,

```
$(function(){
    $("#cat-head img").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("src") == "opeb-arrow.png") {
            $(this).attr("src", "close-arrow.png");
        }
        else {$(this).attr("src", "opeb-arrow.png");}   
        $(this).closest("#cat-head").siblings().toggle('fast');
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Image doesn't tell anything about code.

Comment: Try to put all you `<checkbox>`s into separate `<div>` and apply toggle on it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you used jquery .hide() and .show() methods. These are working in firefox perfectly but in chrome some space left below the hidden divs.

You can use these methods to hide and show for the chrome issue;

```
$('#cat-head').css('display', 'none');
$('#cat-head').css('display', 'block');
```

this solved my problem. Hope it helps.